# How to list all available commands in unix like system?

Tags: unix, qnx-neutrino

I want to list all available commands in a qnx 6.5.0 system. That is all commands that could be ran from the command line.

I think that listing all the contents of the PATH variable will do the job, but I also have to filter the non executable parts.

Is there a simple and easy way to that, using the most simple unix commands ?

NOTE: Our system uses korn shell and most of the unix commands are not included in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into **compgen**. It's a built-in bash command that lists all command available.

Run this:
**compgen -c**

Answer (score 1):

Try using the command:

```
compgen -ac
```